# How to add a dictionary to an empty array in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm creating an empty array in swift like this:

```
var myArray = [String]()
```

and I create a dictionary like this:

```
let dict  = ["Deleted":false] as [String : Any]
```

and I TRY to append the `dic` to `myArray` like this:

```
myArray.append(dict)
```

But the Xcode is complaining with this error:

```
No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'
```

I tried to create `myArray` in a different way like this but this will create other issues in my code as its not String:

```
myArray: [Dictionary<String,Any>]! = nil
```

can someone please advice on this?

**EDIT:**

The suggestions below are correct but I am bumping into another issue here!

To explain this further:

I have a `codeable` like this:

```
struct RequestModel: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var newArray = [String]()
    
}
```

I need to be able to use the `myArray` value for `newArray` to send to an API.

But using a dictionary/myArray throws this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Any]]' to expected argument type '[String]'
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is what I have to send to the API:

```
{
    "var1": "1",
    "var2": "2",
    
    "newArray": [{"Deleted": false}]
}
```

Comment: The array must have the same element type as the item you want to append. First initialize the array `var myArray = [Dictionary<String,Any>]()` then append the item `myArray.append(dict)`

Comment: @vadian, I tried that as I mentioned but this will create other issues in the code. mainly because the myArray is being used in a Codable {} which doesnt seem to like the array with dictionary. I get this error: Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Any]]' to expected argument type '[String]'

Comment: You can't do that. As I said *the array must have the same element type as the item you want to append.* And be aware that Codable doesn't support `Any`.

Comment: so ["Deleted":false] obviously isn't a string, but what string(s) would you expect to send to your API, and how would you expect to get those strings from a dictionary like ["Deleted":false]

Comment: @Shadowrun, please view my edit.

Comment: @drago It wou be much easier if you show your JSON

Comment: @LeoDabus just added my JSON at the end of my question.

Comment: `struct Root: Codable {` `let var1: String` `let var2: String` `let newArray: [Other]` `}` `struct Other: Codable { let Deleted: Bool }`

Comment: @LeoDabus That throws the same error: Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Any]]' to expected argument type '[Other]'

Comment: Of course you need to send an array of Other

Comment: Btw you should always name your properties starting with a lowercase letter `struct Other: Codable {` `let deleted: Bool` `private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {` `case deleted = "Deleted"` `}` `}`

Comment: @LeoDabus, what do you mean by I need to 'send' an array of Other?

Comment: Exactly what you said. Create an array of Other and add your deleted info there. It will be converted to an array of JSON dictionaries when you encode it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want an array of Dictionaries, so you should declare the variable like

```
var myArray = [[String:Any]]()
```

Comment: that gives me the same result as myArray: [Dictionary<String,Any>]! = nil